# socat gives "Resource temporarily unavailable" on OS X High Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra, socat

I am trying to create a virtual local com-port that forwards everything to a remote computer via TCP with this command:

```
sudo socat GOPEN:/dev/ptyp0,ignoreeof TCP:192.168.254.106:8080
2018/09/08 21:48:51 socat[10860] E open("/dev/ptyp0", 012, 0666): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

This is a freshly installed OS X High Sierra, so I doubt I am out of resources.

```
sudo lsof /dev/ptyp0
```

Shows nothing... and I get the same result even if I try ptyp1, ptyp2 etc.

Comment: Why are you trying to open a device special file that doesn’t exist? Are you just copying a command you don’t understand from some online source? It may have come from Linux or some other Unix variant that names pseudo-TTY device files differently than macOS’s BSD-based tradition does. You may need to use macOS-style pseudo-TTY device file naming.

Comment: @Spiff Not sure what you mean by "file that doesn't exist"? That file does DOES exist as "ls /dev/ptyp*" clearly shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just open a random pty and expect it to work. (Actually, you are supposed to open each of them in turn, until you find one that is free) Instead, use the proper `socat` syntax for it:

```
socat PTY,link=/tmp/mytty TCP:192.168.254.106:8080
```

This will open the master side of an available pseudo-terminal, make a symlink under `/tmp/mytty` (modify as appropriate) to the slave side, and forward between the master side and your remote TCP port.

You can now use `/tmp/mytty` (or the slave-pty linked to from it) like a normal tty. ("Virtual local com-port" sounds suspiciously like a Windows term).

BTW, this will work on all platforms that support pseudo terminals, because `socat` uses the platform-appropriate method.

**Edit**

Whatever you see as an option in the Java program you run depends entirely on the Java program you run, which I don't know anything about (and you told us nothing about). It's entirely possible the Java program has additional options to tell it about other tty's. It's also possible it has no such options.

Files under `/dev` are part of a special filesystem called `devfs` which shows the devices available to the kernel. Apparently you are not allowed to create symlinks on it.

So if all your Java program does is to scan for files `/dev/cu.*`, then you are out of luck.

You can always try to find the source for your Java program, and change it. Or even patch the binary (replace the string `/dev/cu` by something else).

Comment: I tried the command and it "might" have worked. However, I still do not see /tmp/mytty as an option in a Java-program that I run. The only option I see there is "/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incomming-Port". Maybe I need some extra parameter or symlink so that OS X (or Java) knows about the new "port" being created?

Comment: I tried running "sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/cu.esp8266 TCP:192.168.254.106:8080" but that "Operation was not permitted".

Comment: Yes, it seems that the java program simply lists /dev/cu.* Now sure why I am not able to create files in /dev/ as root on OS X through :(

Comment: As I said, `devfs` is a different type of filesystem - it gives you access to kernel resources. Apparently symlinks are not implemented in this filesystem, so root or not, you can't create any.

Comment: Sure, it makes sense. However, if there is no "standard way" for applications to fetch a list of ttys from the OS (other than listing /dev/cu.*) then there should be a way to create such links. I doubt Apple just ignored that "feature".

Comment: The "standard way" in BSD is to operate on files. If your Java application doesn't support that, and thinks it must babysit the user by presenting choices based on patterns the programmer felt are sufficient, it's the fault of the Java application. Find the programmer and beat him with a stick. And you're welcome to suggest to Apple they should change the devfs file system (or open source it so other people can change it). BTW, Linux switched years ago from devfs to devtmpfs (and udev), where symlinks work fine.

Comment: And it looks like symlinks [used to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175410/managing-serial-port-names-in-mac-osx-with-symlinks), but Apple disallowed it.